# Game audio libraries for several platforms

Tags: audio, mobile, cross-platform

We're making a multi-platform game targetting both desktops and phones. Specifically:
Windows, Mac, Linux, iPhone, Android and Windows Phone 7.

We're looking for an audio lib. I looked around and it seems it's going to be the best to write a wrapper around several different APIs for the different platforms. The question is, which are the best libraries to wrap/use?

Our requirements are:

- Compatible - the libraries should ideally support old platform versions (e.g. Windows XP).  I also hope to avoid compatibility hell where every platform or platform version has different quirks :)
- Loading of ogg or mp3 files
- Streaming - playing music from disk so we don't have to have a long blocking wait while it's being loaded
- Fading - fade in, fade out, crossfading between music tracks
- No obvious artifacts (such as popping when changing volume)
- The basics - looping music/effects, setting volume

Any recommendations?

I'm leaning towards OpenAL for all platforms except WP7 which seems to require using XNA. Also on Android OpenAL seems to be barely supported so maybe use the native API there? For iPhone I'm not sure how mature support is for OpenAL.

Our language is C# but we have no problems with calling C libraries. Class-based C++ libraries would be a bit more difficult to call from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out libSDL? It seems that Angry Birds is based on it, so it could be quite well what you need.